# Return value from a VBScript function

Tags: function, vbscript, return-value

I have two functions, and I am trying to use the result of one function in the second one. It's going to the `else` part, but it's not printing anything for "cus_number".

How do I get the "cus_number" printed?

```
Function getNumber
    number = "423"
End Function

cus_number = getNumber

If (IsNull(cus_number)) Then
    WScript.Echo "Number is null"
Else
    WScript.Echo "cus_number : " & cus_number
End If
```

Comment: Jill, why don't you accept Richie's answer ?

Comment: @Jill448 [There's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667474/1879699) waiting to be accepted. ;)

Answer (score 90):

To return a value from a VBScript function, assign the value to the name of the function, like this:

```
Function getNumber
    getNumber = "423"
End Function
```

Comment: Does this mean that the function will stop executing after reaching the first assigning the value to its name? For example:
Function getNumber
    If {condition1} Then getNumber = "423"
    ElseIf {condition2} Then getNumber = "567"
    Else getNumber = "890"
End Function

Comment: @B.Sverediuk No, the function will continue until it reaches either the end of the function or encounters an explicit `Exit Function` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you can return a value from a function in VBS:**

```
Function shouldSendEmail(Line)
    Dim returnValue
    If Line = False Then
        returnValue = True
    Else
        returnValue = False
    End If
    wscript.echo returnValue
    shouldSendEmail = returnValue
End Function
```

**Call a function:**

```
wscript.echo shouldSendEmail(true)
```