# Currency conversion function doesn't work

Tags: function, vbscript

I just began a video on VBScript, and after a few tutorials, I decided to create a USD to EUR converter. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim inputMoney
inputMoney = CDbl(InputBox("Enter in the number of USD:"))
MsgBox "The amount of " & inputMoney & " USD in EUR is" & convert_to_eur(inputMoney)
MsgBox exit_mssg()

Function convert_to_eur(amount)
    amount = amount * 0.88
End Function

Function exit_mssg()
    exit_mssg = "Thank you"
End Function
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBScript: Return value from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667421/vbscript-return-value-from-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

In vbscript, functions return a value assigning it to itself

```
Function convert_to_eur(amount)
    convert_to_eur = amount * 0.88
End Function
```

Comment: @lupo19, well, not completely: you used it in the last function. We all are sometimes blind when reading our own code.