# VBScript Function Return

Tags: vbscript, subroutine

I am trying to return a string from a subroutine in VBScript, but I am getting a type mismatch.

Here is the code:

```
main 

Sub Main
  Dim NumofBatches, Batch1 
  CStr(Batch1)
  Batch1 = checkXML("Bar.xml") 
End Sub

'Checks For Batch in ZoneX
Sub checkXML(sFile)
  Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\Projects\Scripts\SQL\" + sFile, 1)
  Dim strLine, x, y
  Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    CStr(StrLine)
    strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
    'String Foo
    If (x > 3) Then
      If (InStr(strLine, """") = 1) Then
        CheckXMl = ""
      Else
        CheckXMl = StrLine
      End If
    End If
  Loop
  objFileToRead.Close
  Set objFileToRead = Nothing
End Sub
```

And I am not sure of the issue, I know the system right now only gets one result from `If (x > 3) Then` portion, but even if it weren't I should only overwrite my result, correct?

Comment: Use `Function() ... End Function` instead of `Sub() ... End Sub` to return a result.

Comment: hmm, this seems to work, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667421/vbscript-return-value-from-a-function) led me to believe otherwise..

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15667474/6352151) to the question you posted is stating exactly what told by @omegastripes. And a quick FYI: This code --> `Cstr(StrLine)` is doing absolutely nothing in your code, plus I believe it is never even entering the `if` part, since you  are never assigning any values to `x` :)

Comment: all the x assignment was boring stuff, simple string operations and batching to known values ect, added nothing to the issue, so I took it out and added the 'string foo in its place.

Comment: BTW, variables passed as arguments to `Sub` or `Function` can be changed within it (if passed `ByRef` which is default), thus it's possible to return a number of values both from `Sub` and `Function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@omegastripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094244/vbscript-function-return#comment67461503_40094244) pointed out, subs don't have a return value, only functions do.

Change

```
Sub checkXML(sFile)
  ...
End Sub
```

to

```
Function checkXML(sFile)
  ...
End Function
```

[See also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w.aspx).