# Function with for loop - How to return in vb | UFT

Tags: function, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I would need support for that. I guess it's an easy one but i would like to get different approach if possible.
I have the following Function and i just want to return value. If possible within a string variable.

```vb
StrVal = "123 Test"

Function IsHaving(StrVal)
Set reg1 = New RegExp
reg1.Gloabl=True
reg1.IgnoreCase=False
reg1.Pattern="\d+"
Set mats = reg.Execute(StrVal)
For Each mat In mats
  return mat.Value
Next
End Function
```

And then passing the value returned in another string

```vb
StrNum = IsHaving(StrVal)
```

I would like to do this way but i am not sure that in vb i can return from a loop for ( within the Function).
Some ideas on that ?

Comment: `Function IsHaving(StrVal) as Collection` and add `mat.value` to the collection and return that at the end.  You dont return, you need to set the value of the same name as the function so in your example `IsHaving=mat.Value`

Comment: Could you illustrate that with an example maybe. I am not familiar with Collection. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `return mat.Value`, just use `IsHaving = mat.Value`. In vbscript, if you want to return a value, then you just need to write `name_of_function = value_to_return`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return value from a VBScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667421/return-value-from-a-vbscript-function)

Comment: Not really responding as i having a loop for in the Function

Comment: It's not really clear for me. Sorry.

Comment: Ok! I got it. Thanks. The notion of Collection is not needed here as i just have an unique string to return and not multiple.